# PostgreSQL query performance when using IN subquery

Tags: postgresql

I'm facing some performance issue on one of my queries (generated by ORM) where you can see this query is taking about 27 seconds to run. It doesn't fully utilise the index on the `voucher` table but instead does a sequential scan.

```
explain analyze select id from "vouchers" where "id" in 
(select "vouchers"."id" 
from "order_items" 
where "vouchers"."voucherable_type" = 'order_items' 
and vouchers.voucherable_id = order_items.id 
and "order_items"."order_id" = '11000060') 
and "vouchers"."deleted_at" is null;
```

```
Seq Scan on vouchers  (cost=0.00..156343970.60 rows=17501040 width=8) (actual time=15868.061..26700.359 rows=1 loops=1)
  Filter: ((deleted_at IS NULL) AND (SubPlan 1))
  Rows Removed by Filter: 35057370
  SubPlan 1
    ->  Result  (cost=0.43..8.45 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=0.000..0.000 rows=0 loops=35057018)
          One-Time Filter: ((vouchers.voucherable_type)::text = 'order_items'::text)
          ->  Index Scan using order_items_order_id_foreign on order_items  (cost=0.43..8.45 rows=1 width=0) (actual time=0.001..0.001 rows=0 loops=8268)
                Index Cond: (order_id = 11000060)
                Filter: (vouchers.voucherable_id = id)
                Rows Removed by Filter: 1
Planning Time: 0.148 ms
Execution Time: 26700.393 ms
```

By rewriting it to below, it uses the index in the vouchers table.

```
explain analyze select vouchers.*
from vouchers , order_items
where "vouchers"."deleted_at" is null
and "vouchers"."voucherable_type" = 'order_items'
and vouchers.voucherable_id = order_items.id
and "order_items"."order_id" = '11000060';
```

```
Nested Loop  (cost=0.99..17.04 rows=1 width=156) (actual time=0.024..0.025 rows=1 loops=1)
  ->  Index Scan using order_items_order_id_foreign on order_items  (cost=0.43..8.45 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=0.008..0.008 rows=1 loops=1)
        Index Cond: (order_id = 11000060)
  ->  Index Scan using vouchers_voucherable_type_voucherable_id_index on vouchers  (cost=0.56..8.58 rows=1 width=156) (actual time=0.013..0.013 rows=1 loops=1)
        Index Cond: (((voucherable_type)::text = 'order_items'::text) AND (voucherable_id = order_items.id))
        Filter: (deleted_at IS NULL)
Planning Time: 0.404 ms
Execution Time: 0.058 ms
```

Why is it behaving so? I've run `analyze` on my `vouchers` table as well.

Here's my table structure

```
CREATE TABLE vouchers (
    id bigserial NOT NULL,
    promotion_id int8 NULL,
    order_item_id int8 NULL,
    voucherable_id int8 NULL,
    voucherable_type varchar(191) NULL,
    code varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    is_active int2 NULL DEFAULT 1,
    user_id int8 NULL,
    CONSTRAINT vouchers_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
CREATE INDEX voucherable_type_index ON vouchers USING btree (voucherable_type);
CREATE INDEX vouchers_code_lower_trigram ON vouchers USING gin (lower((code)::text) gin_trgm_ops);
CREATE INDEX vouchers_code_trigram ON vouchers USING gin (code gin_trgm_ops);
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX vouchers_code_unique ON vouchers USING btree (code);
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX vouchers_code_unique_lower ON vouchers USING btree (lower((code)::text));
CREATE INDEX vouchers_order_item_id_foreign ON vouchers USING btree (order_item_id);
CREATE INDEX vouchers_promotion_id_foreign ON vouchers USING btree (promotion_id);
CREATE INDEX vouchers_user_id_foreign ON vouchers USING btree (user_id);
CREATE INDEX vouchers_voucherable_id_voucherable_type_index ON vouchers USING btree (voucherable_id, voucherable_type);
CREATE INDEX vouchers_voucherable_type_voucherable_id_deleted_index ON vouchers USING btree (voucherable_id, voucherable_type, deleted_at);
CREATE INDEX vouchers_voucherable_type_voucherable_id_index ON vouchers USING btree (voucherable_type, voucherable_id);

ALTER TABLE vouchers ADD CONSTRAINT vouchers_order_item_id_foreign FOREIGN KEY (order_item_id) REFERENCES order_items(id) NOT VALID;
ALTER TABLE vouchers ADD CONSTRAINT vouchers_user_id_foreign FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES users(id) NOT VALID;
```

```
CREATE TABLE order_items (
    id serial NOT NULL,
    order_id int4 NOT NULL,
    order_itemable_id int4 NOT NULL,
    order_itemable_type varchar(191) NOT NULL,
    quantity int4 NOT NULL,
    deleted_at timestamp NULL,
    CONSTRAINT order_items_hash_key_unique UNIQUE (hash_key),
    CONSTRAINT order_items_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
CREATE INDEX idx_order_items_compo_1 ON order_items USING btree (order_itemable_id, order_itemable_type, deleted_at);
CREATE INDEX order_items_order_id_foreign ON order_items USING btree (order_id);

ALTER TABLE order_items ADD CONSTRAINT order_items_order_id_foreign FOREIGN KEY (order_id) REFERENCES orders(id) NOT VALID;
```

Comment: seems like you can rewrite this query using `join` operator

Comment: Your two queries are not semantically equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

If you write a *correlated subquery* like that, PostgreSQL will always perform a nested loop with the subquery as inner loop.

This can be seen as a shortcoming of the optimizer, but there is always a trade-off: the smarter the optimizer gets, the slower it will be, and it will usually also become slower for queries that do not profit from the smartness.

With limitations that can be easily avoided by writing a better query, PostgreSQL is rather unwilling to expend cycles — why punish users that write good SQL only to speed up badly written queries?

Since you mention ORMs: not to get into holy wars here, but the limitations of generated queries are definitely one of their weakest points. But it should be possible to get an ORM to do a simple join.